# K.Uhlenbeck's preprint "A priori estimates for Yang-Mills fields"

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, gauge-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

Does anyone have a copy of the unpublished preprint of Karen Uhlenbeck *A priori estimates for Yang-Mills fields* from around 1986?

It appears to have circulated for some time, and it is quoted in several papers in the field (Uhlenbeck-Yau, Daskalopoulos-Wentworth, De Bartolomeis-Tian,...) sometimes with precise references to theorem numbers. However, I could not find it anywhere on the internet.

The results covered in this preprint are probably proved in other places by now, but I'd still be interested in reading it.

Comment: I do have it, I think. But I am out of town this week. I can check my filing cabinet next week, and if it's there, I'll scan it in and post a link.

Comment: That'd be great! Thanks a lot in either case...

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried asking *her* for a copy?

Comment: @Willie:  I wrote to her asking if she had a copy.

Comment: I just heard back from Karen, She said: 

I found a manuscript in my drawer entitled "a prior estimates for Yang-Mills fields".  I am pretty sure that the results must be in papers of Tom Otway. Also the paper of Peter Price must do about the same thing. I got stuck on implementing them, and never followed through.  I had long ago forgotten about it. I may be able to get them scanned on Monday.  I will then send you the scan.

When I get the scan from Karen, I will make it available.

Comment: I have a scanned copy of the paper. I do not want to put the file at my webpage, but I am happy to send it to Dick if Karen could not scan. 

The paper has an overlap with my paper, which is available at

http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.jmsj/1230129890



Comment: Okay, so the Price paper is most likely this one: http://www.springerlink.com/content/n47q6v23520j5q33/  But I am not sure which Otway paper she is referring to. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry it took so long. The scanned version of Uhlenbeck's preprint is available here:

http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~karigiannis/uhlenbeck-preprint.pdf

I can leave it there for a few months, at least.

Comment: It is newer than what I have.

Comment: It is very likely the "final" version. Sometime while I was a student of Yau, probably around 2000, Yau asked for a copy of this preprint from his former student Conan Leung, and this was faxed to him. Conan probably obtained it from Uhlenbeck in the early 1990's.